# What is the meaning of おごっちゃう in this sentence

Tags: meaning

> 本当は常連さんにだけのサービスなんだけど、お客様好みだからあたしおごっちゃう！

I know ちゃう  comes from  しまう
ちゃう =　when the verb ends with て = 食べて ＝たべちゃう
　
じゃう =　when the verb ends with で = 飲んで＝のんじゃう

て and  で are already included and it is not necessary to put them

But I can't figure out which is the verb in  おごっちゃう

Answer (score 2):

The verb that seems to be throwing you off is [奢る{おごる}(jisho.org's definition)](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A5%A2%E3%82%8B), a godan verb meaning to pay for someone else's stuff, often a meal. Since it's a godan verb, the te-form is おごって. From there you get おごっちゃう.

> あたしおごっちゃう
> It's my treat

Comment: Thank you very much, I found some interesting phrases using this verb奢る  that give a little more meaning to the translation in this page:
https://nihongomaster.com/japanese/dictionary/word/54474/ogoru
Sentences like:
一杯おごらせて下さい。Let me buy you a drink.
友達にご飯をおごってもらった。My friends treated me to a meal.
Thank you it helped me a lot.   
Un saludo desde México. Amigo!
It would be easier if the Japanese put the kanjis to identify words like these    笑!!!

Comment: @SamaelLara - If the て-form is おごって, there are only three possibilities for the dictionary form. It’s either おごう (ending with う like 買う), おごつ (ending with つ like 待つ) or おごる (ending with る like 帰る). I’m sure only the last one is listed in dictionaries.